# Codeigniter- why do i have to specify application folder name in html form action?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, action, href

```
<form id="search" action="/app_name/index.php/index/search" method="post">
```

I've noticed that when specifying a link in php, you don't have to specify application name:

```
echo form_open('index/function');
```

Is it possible to avoid specifying application name in html form action?
Sorry if this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Use `site_url('index/search')`

Answer (score 1):

set base url in config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

and use it like below

```
<form id="search" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index/search" method="post">
```

OR

```
<form id="search" action="<?php echo $this->config->base_url(); ?>index/search" method="post">
```

you need to load url helper in autoload or in controller
 `$this->load->helper('url');`

Comment: hey thanks for the response. I'm wondering if specifying this http://localhost/codeigniter/ may cause an issue if someone else uses it. For instance, someone I know is using localhost directly to go application as oppose to specifying localhost/codeigniter. Can site_url be a better choice?

Comment: You could leave it blank and let CI guess it at runtime. I usually do like this and never had problems, both on Linux and Windows Servers

Comment: @shn yes you can use `site_url("index/search");`

Comment: Ya i've decided to go with site_url since its quicker and doesn't require me to change config. Thanks for the help though.